# Django: Access the entire pk_set of pre_add and pre_remove of M2M Signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals, m2m

I have two models Group and Child as defined below, The Group has a M2M relation to the Child.

When the m2m field children in the Group model is changed then all the add events and remove events are separated into different action

```
class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    req_categories = ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=Categories.choices, max_length=100))


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categories = ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=Categories.choices, max_length=100))
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child, blank=True)
```

I want a way to access the pk_set of pre_add and pre_remove at a single place to perform some validation

currently I have a validation rule that says atleast N number of children should exist so if I place the validation on pre_remove for an action where i removed some child and added some child then the validation error will be thrown even though the upcoming `pre_add` action will take care of the contraint

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Group.children.through)
def child_models_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == "pre_add":
        do validation ....

    if action == "pre_remove":
        do validation ....
```